# I am using phonenumbers in python to figure out the carrier of a number. I keep getting blank output

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, sms, phone-number

I am using `phonenumbers` in Python to figure out the carrier of a number. I keep getting blank output. Here is my code:

```
import phonenumbers
import phonenumbers.carrier

num_object = None

while num_object is None:
    try:
        num = input("phone number: ")
        num_object = phonenumbers.parse("+1 {}".format(num), region="US")
    except Exception as error:
        print("ERROR: {}".format(error))

carrier = phonenumbers.carrier.name_for_number(num_object, "en")
print(carrier)
```

Comment: is it printing the exception?

Comment: No. I’m talking about the print(carrier) at the bottom

Comment: What is the number you're using? For a start, it only makes sense with mobiles. Additionally, the carrier information may not be available for all numbers (especially due to the fact a number could be valid yet still not in use). And you may want to take into account you only get the *original* carrier the number was allocated to, useless in countries with phone number portability. Perhaps it would be a good idea to print out `num_object` to see what it thinks it is.

Comment: right, but that would be emtpy if the try block wasnt executed, so was it?